# How can I removed item from array by index if do not know index value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have model

```
function row() {
    this.name = '';
    this.rulingValue = '';
    this.pathToImage = '';
    this.rulingType = '';
    this.dateStart = '';
    this.dateEnd = '';
}
```

and array `var jsonData = [];`

I have table

```
<table class="table" id="data-table">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and button to add row ti this table. When I add row to table I add it to array too.

methos for add row to array

```
function add() {
    var item = new row();
    item.name = document.getElementById("ruling-name").value;
    item.pathToImage = document.getElementById("path-to-image").value;
    item.rulingValue = document.getElementById("ruling-value").value;
    item.rulingType = document.getElementById("ruling-type").value;
    item.dateStart = document.getElementById("dtp_input1").value;
    item.dateEnd = document.getElementById("dtp_input2").value;
    jsonData.push(item);
    ddRow(item);
}
```

method for add row to table

```
function ddRow(item) {
    const newRow = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
    newRow.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));
    newRow.insertCell(1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.pathToImage));        
    newRow.insertCell(2).appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.rulingValue));
    newRow.insertCell(3).appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.rulingType));
    newRow.insertCell(4).appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.dateStart));
    newRow.insertCell(5).appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.dateEnd));
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btn.onclick = function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    };
    var t = document.createTextNode("delete");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    newRow.insertCell(6).appendChild(btn);
}
```

All work fine But I can not remove current row from array

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove(); // removed row from table
```

But how can I removed this row from array?

**EDIT**

Yes I see this solution

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

But How can I make this?

```
var index = jsonData .indexOf(??????????????????????);
```

I tried

```
    var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var index = jsonData.indexOf(row)
    alert(index);
```

and I have "`udefined`"

my array in json
[image]

Comment: Are you include jquery library in your html ? jquery tag was missing on your question so why i am asking

Comment: `array.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: have a look at this: [remove element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Is using jQuery function "data" instead of the array an option? It attaches data to DOM elements. So, I guess they automatically get removed when removing the DOM element.

Comment: @ mm759 Can you share some example?

Comment: @ Kevin Kloet I tried this but I can not detect index

Comment: Are you getting correct values in `row` and `jsonData` ?

Answer (score 1):

To find index of item based on your condition you can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)  function on the array.

```
jsonData.findIndex(function(item){ return item.name === "My name" })
```

The function is not implemented in IE, but you can use polyfill from the link above.

Comment: names in array maybe equals

Comment: Since you are already using ES6, you can use arrow function to make this even more elegant. `jsonData.findIndex(item => item.name === "My name")`

Comment: I tell you that the array can be elements of the same name. where does the arrow? how do I know the index of an element?

Comment: function(item){ return item.name === "My name" } inside an findIndex helps you to find correct element. 
In this example it try to find index of item which name is "My name"

Comment: and if I have an array of such ["pavel","pavel","pavel","pavel","pavel"]

Comment: jsonData.indexOf("pavel") is good enough in this case. The difference is that `indexOf` search by the item value and `findIndex` by the condition. This is why for your complex structure is better `findIndex`

Comment: or do you want to remove all "pavel" occurrence? in this case you have to do:
let index = jsonData.indexOf("pavel")
while (index!==-1 ){
  // do what you want with index
  index = jsonData.indexOf("pavel")
}

Comment: I want pres to row in table and delete this row from this table and from array becouse when I press add I add row to table and to array!!!